# Pumping water into two 10m3 tanks that drains separtely and using a single float switch

Tags: plumbing, water, pump, water-tank

I have this project to pump water (from a solar pump inside a bore well) into two 10m<sup>3</sup> (10.000Litres) water tanks. The pump maximum flow is at 5 m<sup>3</sup>/h.

The tanks have individual drain pipes and one important rule is that, drain one tank entirely SHOULD NOT drain the other entirely.

I planned to use only one float switch for simplicity. So that when water level drops it automatically activates the pump.

Here is an illustration:
[image]

PS: The tank on the right has 2 drain pipes

The base of the tanks are at height of 5 meters from ground.

Now the issue is that water in the tanks is used randomly and one tank might be used a lot more that the other, so I came up with solution:

[image]

This is how i think this is going to work:

- The T joint pipe connects both the tank at a specific level. That level is above the level where the float switch toggles.
- When the left tank drains faster, if the level goes below the T joint, then water from the right tanks will drain into the left tank so as to equalize water level in both tanks. When that happens the float switch must activate the pump to refill the tanks.
- In case it is night (there are no batteries, pump works only during the day) either tank can be totally drained without affecting much the other one, it will only affect it up the level of T-Joint.

Now, I've never done anything like this, and it is going to cost money, so I'd like to know if there is anything wrong in my design or if there is a better way (simpler, more cost effective...) to do this please let me know.

Comment: I think you also need to think about making sure that both tanks are filled equally.  If the left tank drains completely, when power comes back on, the pump needs to run until both tanks are totally full, right?  Is that the case if the left tank is empty?  What about the right tank?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Thanks for your input, and you have a point! I didn"t think about that, but this my assumption. If the left tank drains completely (assumning the right one has a good amount of water) when the pump turns on, water in the right tank will obviously reach the T-joint level first, making it harder for water to keep flowin in there, so it will naturally flow much more in the left tank (path of least resistance) until it also reach the T-joint and then both tanks will grow more or less equally till the switch toggles and pump shuts down.

Comment: @JPhi1618 In the worst case the right tank will quickly fill first the float switch will turn off the pump, at that time if water in the left tank is below the T-join level then water in the right tank will flow into the left tank, till they equalize and if water in the right tank drops enough, the float switch turns on and pump refills.

Comment: I think the only issue would be if the pump shuts off before it reaches the Tee.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yeah right, for that reason, the float switch must be installed carefully to only toggle above the Tee.

Comment: "drain one tank entirely SHOULD NOT drain the other entirely" - why? You want one in reserve at all times? Otherwise teat it as one large tank, just like regular incoming water and Tee all your supply pipes together. "water in the tanks is used randomly and one tank might be used a lot more that the other" - then make it 'one tank'. To do reserve, all the 'drains' have to be higher except one that has a valve you can open in emergency that feeds everything, not just w/e those pipes on one side do.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting the tanks together at the lowest point would allow them to equalize their levels. This would prevent a single tank from being drained while there is still available water in the other.

You could add a new connection to both tanks or depending on the existing piping arraignment, simply connect the two drains together at the highest level.

Comment: Connecting the tanks at the bottom will keep the water levels in the two tanks at the same level, all the way down to the connection between them. If that connection is at the bottom, it will not satisfy the OP's stricture "...one important rule is that, drain one tank entirely SHOULD NOT drain the other entirely."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, I missed that requirement. I do wonder as to why that is a requirement.